# Approaches to commit examples of errors, mistakes or problematic outputs with Git

Tags: git, logging

Often times I have to deal with many side-effects (errors) when working with other developers git repos. These are typically due to my own system settings. Everyone on the team has different setups.

I would like to be able to show other developers exactly what I had to go through to deal with their code- errors, new installs, etc. This can be with screenshots during the process, and terminal output. Hopefully it will help narrow down those issues.

What is the proper way to include terminal / console output and adding screenshots to commits?

Answer (score 0):

Everybody makes mistakes. Committing artifacts actually into the repository doesn't sound like a good policy for helping to learn from those mistakes.

To address your main problem, the problem that committed code works on some machines but not others, consider using a container environment such as Docker. Provide a Dockerfile at the top level of your repo which provides an end-to-end environment with the necessary operating system, support libraries, language libraries, and appropriate versioning artifacts.

Each developer may customize their own local tools for development, but at the end of the day, it should be required that whatever work they do must result in the expected and correct behavior *inside the container*, and that any necessary changes to the runtime environment, dependencies, etc., are reflected in commits that actually change the container definition itself (e.g. Dockerfile) and update any tests accordingly.

Now when someone checks out your repo, they only need `docker build ...` and `docker run ...` (commands which themselves can be stored in shell scripts or build tools like Make), and everyone should be able to reproduce exactly the same build artifacts.

Better still is to include some acceptance tests that will do this automatically in certain situations, such as merging into a special branch, or even on all commits, and automatically run a set of tests inside of the built container artifact.

To address the general problem of communicating about the side-effects of others' mistakes, consider using various code review practices.

If your team practices code review using some type of git interface, such as with GitHub, then adding snippets of shell code, pasted shell output, or other examples or screenshots could be appropriate in a code review setting, such as a pull request. This is best for mistakes that are unique to each unit of work being performed, such as a coding error, a genuine bug, or an aspect of an attempted solution that has an uninteded side-effect.

If some kinds of errors persist over time, consider that the problem is not solely on the side of those committing the errors. Rather, some of the blame lies with not having good centralized documentation or tooling to consistently overcome the 'gotchas.'

In that case, you could make a separate team repo called something like 'documentation' or 'developer-workflow' or something, which is intended to just hold Markdown documents with detailed explanations about commonly difficult topics like rebasing, commit hooks, good habits, etc.

It may also hold example code, like for configuring pre-commit hooks in git, or how to install a custom linting tool, so that team members with less expertise over certain kinds of tools can still easily benefit from good tooling created by more experienced members of the team.

This has the added benefit that you can use the code review process itself as you add and update the explanations and examples of good workflows. And it allows you to frame the problem constructively, as in "here are some helpful walkthroughs and examples" rather than rubbing someone's nose in their mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should not interact using your project branch. There are many other ways for it: IMs, issue trackers, wikis, even emails.

You *could* use a tracker which uses git as a transport (from google: [1](https://github.com/neithernut/git-dit), [2](https://github.com/dspinellis/gi), [3](https://github.com/duplys/git-issues), etc - none of them I actually tried), but I have not heard of any being mature enough to actually use it, and they should be in other branch/repository than your development.